# cors with angularjs and asp.net empty website

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, cors

I am creating a simple client with angularjs in asp.net empty web site, and i have wcf service when i am calling service from angular js it is hitting the method in service(running on other port number), in the google chrome under network data is returning from service in json format, problem is every time it is going to failure method and showing status as 404 and data is undefined,

sample code form angular js app.js to enable cors,

```
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
```

the code in web config is as,

```
<system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol> 
</system.webServer>
```

my request for service is,

```
$http.jsonp(
    'http://localhost:56733/Service1.svc/GetData?callback=JSON_CALLBACK";'
    )
    .then(function (data, status, header, confi) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (error, data) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Is your ASP.NET end point properly configured to respond to JSONP requests? If you already allow CORS why not use normal AJAX calls?

Comment: you dont need jsonp... use $http.get

Comment: thank you very much "Entre", now i am able to get the required data, using $http.get method but i did not understand how it works now, at every place and blogs its recommended to use jsonp to work with cross domain, yes i know i have change in the web config also. Can you help me to under stand this ?

Answer (score 0):

As per Entre comment i used this and nothing else, it working for me now, :)

```
http.get(
'http://localhost:56733/Service1.svc/GetData'
)
    .then(function (data, status, header, confi) {
        console.log(data);
    }, function (error, data) {
    console.log(error);
});
```